# Expo Error on launching the app. "ApiV2Error: Account not found. "

Tags: react-native, expo, yarn-v2, expo-go

Good day,

I am using and expo version 5.4.12
I tried running my app I got an error on launch

```
"ApiV2Error: Account not found.
    at ApiV2Client._requestAsync"
```

anyone who had this issue ? please help me.

Comment: My coworker currently has this problem, I'll let you know if we find something

Comment: Thank you @Matjia Martic for his comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694849/18245524
this works for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For us, the problem was that the owner property in app.json did not match the owner for whatever account you're logged into on expo-cli or your expo go app. So just try to check if owner property is correct.

Comment: Hey dude did this work for you? if it did please mark this answer so other people would know.

Comment: To get rid of this error you need to logout of expo on your command line with `expo logout` and then launch the app again. It worked for me. Found solution from a friend who pointed me to this answer on github: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2436#issuecomment-682486361

Answer (score 12):

You can run:

```
npx expo start --offline
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an actual solution but for me it worked by logging out from the terminal with **expo logout** and after I relaunched expo the message was gone.

Answer (score 2):

`expo logout` worked for me and it seems that command clears local login state. This is probably happening because you're collaborating on a project where you aren't the owner. Expo apparently authenticates per user, not per project, which can be confusing.

You'll eventually need to run `expo login` to [actually publish your app with the Expo App Services (EAS)](https://docs.expo.dev/eas/). It's worth reading through the EAS guides to learn more about what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in circles with this error (expo logout + login did not work) until I tried `eas logout` as suggested in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuzaoTZpBrw That worked for me