# Error message shown up while running "expo start" (Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning)

Tags: react-native, expo

I just cloned my Expo project to my new macbook. I have installed the packages and expo global using yarn, but no luck to run `expo start`. The Error message below:

```
(node:39137) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /Users/hurraychak/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/rest/client.js:28
    name = "ApiV2Error";
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hurraychak/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/getExpoGoIntermediateCertificate.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
(node:39137) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:39137) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:39137) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /Users/hurraychak/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/rest/client.js:28
    name = "ApiV2Error";
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hurraychak/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/api/getExpoGoIntermediateCertificate.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
(node:39137) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 7)
```

I can't find anyone discussing this error on the internet. I found this error message being displayed while running `expo`. Please help me to solve this with thanks!

Comment: Wich version of `expo` are you using? Also, to start your app in expo you must run `npx expo start` instead of just `expo start`. You can find more about this [here](https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421)

Comment: you may refer below where they have similar kind of issues with a specific expo version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72784708/expo-error-on-launching-the-app-apiv2error-account-not-found

Comment: "expo": "^49.0.7"
I am using `yarn expo start`, and tried `yarn expo logout`. Both of them are not working because it's not able to run `expo`

Comment: It shows 0.10.11 when I run `expo --version`.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by running `nvm use18` to use the latest node version.

Previously, I tried upgrading node by both command and downloading but the system is still using node of version 10.xx.xx and I don't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by HurrayChak essentially worked for me, but was initially confounded by me using WebStorm.

I needed to go to Settings->Languages & Frameworks->Node.js and point to the correct node version there. Running nvm use 18 in the WebStorm Terminal window doesn't work when running package.json scripts from the WebStorm UI.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35490213)